# Error while Installing Openrazer-meta and polychromatic in Xubuntu

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, xubuntu, ppa

I have an Razer mouse, I want to configure it using UBuntu , but I am not able to do that because of these errors.

```
sudo apt install openrazer-meta
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
openrazer-meta : Depends: openrazer-driver-dkms (= 2.8.0~ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going 
to be installed
              Depends: openrazer-daemon (= 2.8.0~ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be 
installed
              Depends: python3-openrazer (= 2.8.0~ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be 
installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Add the output of `apt cache policy` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the installed openrazer package:

```
sudo apt remove --auto-remove openrazer-meta
```

Reinstall the package:

```
sudo apt install openrazer-meta
```

For more info visit: https://openrazer.github.io/